Generic enum with localized string in SwiftUI
I'd like to have a function that can take both enum A and enum B and display the raw values in a menu. so i use type T to make the function generic, and T follows the localized protocol i defined so that the value can be localized. below is my code which compiles but doesn't show any of the string literals in my string catalog. i have other kinds of localized string work well.
please let me know what's wrong with the code?
protocol StringEnumLocalizable {
  func localizedString() -> LocalizedStringKey
}

enum A: String, CaseIterable, Codable, StringEnumLocalizable {
  case a1 = "a1"
  case a2 = "a2"

  func localizedString() -> LocalizedStringKey {
    return LocalizedStringKey(self.rawValue)
  }
}

enum B: String, CaseIterable, Codable, StringEnumLocalizable {
  case b1 = "a1"
  case b2 = "a2"

  func localizedString() -> LocalizedStringKey {
    return LocalizedStringKey(self.rawValue)
  }
}

private func customMultiSelectionsView<T: StringEnumLocalizable>(
  options: [T]
) -> some View {
  Menu {
    ForEach(options, id: \.self) { option in            
      Text(option.localizedString())
    }
}

